# How do I avoid accidentally turning on the wrong scenes in HomeKit?

Tags: homekit

We have various HomeKit accessories set up in different rooms around the house. Specifically, we have HomeKit lights (Nanoleaf) in our kid's room, which are set to a very specific (obviously, very dark) scene when they're asleep.

We also have whole-home scenes (and, for some fiddly reasons having to do with the Nanoleaf app it's extremely difficult to delete these, even if we wanted to) which set the kid's lights to very bright colors as well.

I'm afraid to use Siri to set any scenes because its voice recognition is frankly terrible, and it will happily set the kid's lights to a blaring 100% cool white if it mishears me.  It hasn't misheard me in this *specific* way yet, but it's been close.

I'm afraid to use the Home app because all the whole-home scenes are visible in every room, so if I bring up the "Office" room it's going to show me every scene that will turn on the kid's lights as well. Since there's lots of horizontal scrolling and long-pressing to do various things it's easy to slip and press the wrong thing.

So, the question is: if we want to make it easy to set a light to a particular color in the parents' bedroom or the office at night time, how can we do it in such a way that we are *sure* we won't provide an opportunity to wake up the kid?

(The only thought I have so far is to make custom shortcuts with some odd phonetic prefix, like "Cowabunga Office White", so Siri won't get confused, and then add these to the home screen so that the kid's scenes and whole-house scenes are on a completely different screen, hidden within a drawer.  But this seems awkward and doesn't fully address the concern that I want those accessories locked behind a confirmation dialog until 9AM.)